# Can I use meld to interactively review hunks for git add --patch

Tags: git, meld

Can git be configured so that after cherry-picking/merging a remote fork (with `--no-commit`?) I can `git add --patch` to use meld to allow me to review the hunks as I go through them?

Comment: I don't know how to achive it with meld, but the *awesome* Vim-Fugitive plugin (https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) allows you to do that in Vim. If you're interested, there's a screencast: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-working-with-the-git-index/

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `git add --patch` one of the prompt options is `e` for edit.  This should use whatever editor you have configured (`core.editor` in your git config file).

Comment: I've been using the e option (default config), but Meld is a visual diff tool, will configuring it as the core.editor work, ie. will I be able to see the unpatched, patched, and patch side by side?

Comment: Only one way to know for sure!

Comment: Yep as I suspected, it's treated as a simple editor.